# how to get the mobile keypad type programatically using j2me midp2.0?

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I want to know the type of the mobile keypad whether it is qwerty keypad or normal keypad programatically. And based on this, I have to perform some key events of the mobile. How to get this?

Comment: Iffff I had designed mobile OS, I would have abstracted this difference from developers. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Nokia devices you can use the *`com.nokia.keyboard.type`* system property. More information on the [link](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-E56C1B89-5BC2-475B-A487-A514D1396D76.html)